# Is it possible to modify json data before displaying it with out saving it to a file first

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am pulling data from witter and I was wondering if I could add an element to part of the array with a predetermined value without saving the json to file? I am displaying the pulled data as is but there is another element I need to add to it. So is it possible to edit the json data before.

I have a file that gets the data and a java script file that parses the data into a nice display. What would be the best way to go about adding an element to the array before it gets displayed on the page

Here is the array. I just want to add a variable called is_selected with a default value of 0

```
Array
(
[statuses] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [metadata] => Array
                (
                    [result_type] => recent
                    [iso_language_code] => en
                )

            [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 21:50:00 +0000 2014
            [id] => 4.3770592875932E+17
            [id_str] => 437705928759320577
            [text] => 2 new iPhone leads have just broken within 5 minutes of each. What are the odds of that?! No phone for a few days then!!!!
            [source] => Twitter for iPad
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 221418717
                    [id_str] => 221418717
                    [name] => Craig Price
                    [screen_name] => CraigPrice1
                    [location] => Glanamman
                    [description] => Beer & Sport!
                    [url] => 
                    [entities] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [urls] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [protected] => 
                    [followers_count] => 269
                    [friends_count] => 765
                    [listed_count] => 1
                    [created_at] => Tue Nov 30 16:28:40 +0000 2010
                    [favourites_count] => 520
                    [utc_offset] => 0
                    [time_zone] => London
                    [geo_enabled] => 1
                    [verified] => 
                    [statuses_count] => 2852
                    [lang] => en
                    [contributors_enabled] => 
                    [is_translator] => 
                    [is_translation_enabled] => 
                    [profile_background_color] => 0F0F0F
                    [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                    [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                    [profile_background_tile] => 1
                    [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435485486153756672/cSzrw5eX_normal.jpeg
                    [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435485486153756672/cSzrw5eX_normal.jpeg
                    [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/221418717/1392662771
                    [profile_link_color] => FA0000
                    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => EB0000
                    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => C0DFEC
                    [profile_text_color] => 333333
                    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                    [default_profile] => 
                    [default_profile_image] => 
                    [following] => 
                    [follow_request_sent] => 
                    [notifications] => 
                )

            [geo] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [place] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [retweet_count] => 0
            [favorite_count] => 0
            [entities] => Array
                (
                    [hashtags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [symbols] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [urls] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [user_mentions] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [favorited] => 
            [retweeted] => 
            [lang] => en
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [metadata] => Array
                (
                    [result_type] => recent
                    [iso_language_code] => en
                )

            [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 21:26:01 +0000 2014
            [id] => 4.3769989372629E+17
            [id_str] => 437699893726289920
            [text] => @Mogz1457 how about a broken IPhone 3 eh?
            [source] => Twitter for iPhone
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 4.3757491419192E+17
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 437574914191917056
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 347149526
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 347149526
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => Mogz1457
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2353482857
                    [id_str] => 2353482857
                    [name] => Gwilym McCann
                    [screen_name] => theBigg_Mac
                    [location] => Cymru/Wales
                    [description] => The original Big Mac
                    [url] => 
                    [entities] => Array
                        (
                            [description] => Array
                                (
                                    [urls] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [protected] => 
                    [followers_count] => 5
                    [friends_count] => 6
                    [listed_count] => 0
                    [created_at] => Wed Feb 19 23:31:15 +0000 2014
                    [favourites_count] => 1
                    [utc_offset] => 
                    [time_zone] => 
                    [geo_enabled] => 
                    [verified] => 
                    [statuses_count] => 3
                    [lang] => en
                    [contributors_enabled] => 
                    [is_translator] => 
                    [is_translation_enabled] => 
                    [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                    [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                    [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                    [profile_background_tile] => 
                    [profile_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
                    [profile_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
                    [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2353482857/1392853158
                    [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                    [profile_text_color] => 333333
                    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                    [default_profile] => 1
                    [default_profile_image] => 1
                    [following] => 
                    [follow_request_sent] => 
                    [notifications] => 
                )

            [geo] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [place] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [retweet_count] => 0
            [favorite_count] => 0
            [entities] => Array
                (
                    [hashtags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [symbols] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [urls] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [user_mentions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [screen_name] => Mogz1457
                                    [name] => Morgan Williams
                                    [id] => 347149526
                                    [id_str] => 347149526
                                    [indices] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 0
                                            [1] => 9
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [favorited] => 
            [retweeted] => 
            [lang] => en
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to loop in your array and add the required field `is_selected = 0` at each iteration

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    $array[$key]['is_selected'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: @user3347956 just remember to change `$array` with your actual array variable

Comment: @user3347956 you are welcome dude, if you feel the answer was correct you might consider to accept the answer. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: I tried this but i keep coming back with this error

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\4th\twitdb2\get_tweets.php on line 25 

line 25 being 
$tweets[$key]['is_selected'] = 0;